# QFile does not open file

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore

```
QLabel* codeLabel = new Qlabel;

QFile file("C:\index.txt");
file.open(stderr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
QByteArray data;
data = file.readAll();

codeLabel->setText("test"+QString(data));
file.close();
```

Then there is only "test" in QLabel.
Help, Please

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the fact you should escape backslashes within C-style strings (`c:\\index.txt`), you have a problem with the following sequence:

```
//                           vvvvvvvvv
file.open(stderr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
:
data = file.readAll();
//          ^^^^
```

What exactly did you *think* was going to happen when you opened the file write-only, then tried to read it? You need to open it for reading such as with `QIODevice::ReadOnly` or `QIODevice::ReadWrite`.

On top of that, you should check the return code of all functions that fail by giving you a return code. You currently have no idea whether the `file.open()` worked or not.

I'm also not convinced that you should be opening `stderr` (which is really an ouput "device") for input. You'll almost certainly never get any actual data coming *in* on that file descriptor, which is probably why your input is empty.

You need to step back and ask *what* you're trying to acheive. For example, are you trying to capture everything your process sends to standard error? If so, it's not going to work that way.

If you're just trying to read the `index.txt` file, you're using the wrong overload. Remove the `stderr` parameter altogether:

```
file.open (QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

If it's something *else* you're trying to do, add that to the question.

Comment: Thanks, but the situation didn't change, after 
file.open(stderr, QIODevice::ReadOnly)

Comment: besides checking returns values like open(), also check errorString()  for details when they return false.

Answer (score 2):

```
file.open(stderr, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
```

this closes the file again and reopens with the stderr stream in write only mode

you'll want to change that to

```
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
QFile file("C:\index.txt");
```

Here you try to open a file called: `C:index.txt` because `'\i'` is converted to `i`. You want to double you backslash:

```
QFile file("C:\\index.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you *read* from a file you opened *write-only*.